# Stuck at single angle-bracket prompt

Tags: bash

I experimentally ran `if bat1 == 1 then echo yes fi` and am stuck in a single-angle-bracket-prompt purgatory in which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd> fails to open the door.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>** should do the trick

You should write something more like:

```
[ $bat1 -eq 1 ] && echo yes
```

or

```
if [ $bat1 -eq 1 ]; then echo yes ; fi
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thought I'd checked that. cheers :)